# What has been written about English completive "up"?

Tags: syntax, english, particles, adverbs

English *up* can be used to express completion or thoroughness: *eat it up* 'eat all of it', *beat him up* 'beat him thoroughly'. What research exists on this construction, from any angle (syntax, historical semantics, Construction Grammar, etc.)? How did it arise and when? What are its exact semantics? How is it that *up* can function as an argument for verbal valency purposes ('He swept the dirt up' but *'He swept the dirt') given that it appears to lack any of the usual semantics of arguments?

Comment: Huh? What does that last sentence mean? You'll have to specify why **you** think _up_ functions as an argument (I certainly wouldn't, and don't understand the examples' relevance to the issue), and what **you** think the usual semantics of arguments are.

Comment: I mean that the grammaticality asymmetry between *He swept it up* and **He swept it* looks to me like the grammaticality asymmetry between *He put it on the table* and **He put it*, suggesting that completive *up* fills a valency requirement of the verb in the former example just as the PP *on the table* does in the latter.

Comment: You could say there is a predicate frame where an adverbial constituent and an object are both complements, so you need both *up* and *it* in that predicate frame. In other predicate frames around the verbs *put* or *sweep*, there are other complements. You could say *up* is often not literally a direction any more, but has acquired other senses as a conceptual metaphor. Or you could say that, regardless of its history, *sweep up* is best considered a separate verb different from simple *sweep*. The you could analyse what *up* as part of a phrasal verb does to its meaning, like suffixes.

Comment: Note also that this sense of completion probably already existed in Proto-Germanic, considered that it also exists in Dutch and German.

Comment: Well, whatever the valency requirements are or may be, whatever is going on with _up_ is going on with lots of German trennbare Vorsilben. Not to mention English phrasal verbs, of which there are thousands.

Comment: Tons of research on this topic. Take a look at Denison 1985 https://www.escholar.manchester.ac.uk/uk-ac-man-scw:1b2567 or Thim 2012.

Comment: @Alex B., thanks for the Denison reference! Do you have more details on the Thim citation? Google is failing me.

Comment: Thim 2012 http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/174351

Comment: In traditional English grammar "up" is labelled an *adverb* but it would otherwise very often be more like a *particle*, so I added tags for both.

Comment: Um...why is "he swept it" marked as ungrammatical? It's perfectly acceptable to me in, e.g. the following discourse: *A: Has John swept the kitchen floor yet?  B: Yes, he swept it yesterday.*  Here's an attested example: "No, I mean, he swept it, mopped it. It was immaculate" http://slangcity.com/movie_quote/gone_baby_gone.html

Comment: @P Elliott, I hadn't thought of that kind of usage. I've replaced 'it' with 'the dirt' in the question; I'm pretty sure *'He swept the dirt' is ungrammatical in any context, at least for me.

Comment: Indeed *to sweep* and *to sweep up* take different semantic roles for their direct objects and the latter doesn't even have to have a direct object. *To sweep* takes a surface etc whereas *to sweep up* takes a spillage, etc.